# How do you call "hiring manager" in German?

Tags: meaning, word-usage, word-choice, noun

I have found the word "Personalverantwortlicher", "Vorgesetzte" and "Chef" and I couldn't decide which one fits here.

By "hiring manager," I mean the person responsible for hiring the employee; when the employee is hired, that hiring manager is the future employee's boss.

Comment: Could you outline what you understand by "hiring manager"? My own guess would be that they are a "manager of hiring", i.e. someone who is superior to employees whose main task is recruitment, but I'm not sure whether that is correct, and without knowing that, it is hard to give a definitive answer here.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper Sure! I have just added the definition to my post.

Comment: To me it is not clear what exactly means "responsible for hiring the employee". The process depends on the size and structure of the company. A team leader or project manager might find out that a new employee is needed, a manager of some biger organizational unit might have to approve the request, a human resources manager might be responsible for the formal process of hiring. There might be different types of "boss" from a technical or organizational point of view... I'm not sure the person responsible for hiring will always be the same as the future employee's boss.

Comment: Agree with @Bodo it's unclear because there might be a relevant difference between "fachlich vorgesetzt" (team lead i.e.) and "disziplinarisch vorgesetzt" (HR perspective).

Comment: So it seems to me that you are not treating "hiring manager" as a compound noun (manager in charge of hiring people) but just as the manager who is hiring in a particular instance. (I think this will change which word is stressed in English.) That will make a difference.

Answer (score 1):

"Hiring manager", refers to the manager, which is *currently* "hiring" for their department. Thus, we must assume that "hiring" is the present participle of hire. Then, the most fitting translation of this term would be:

> **einstellende Führungskraft**

The disctinction between noun and present participle is important. The noun "hiring" would refer to the "the act of starting to employ someone" (https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/hiring). Then, "hiring manager" would have a different meaning, since the manager now manages the acts of starting to employ someone (cf. a human resources manager manages human resources and a logistics manager manages logistics). In the same sense the german "Einstellungsmanager" does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Früher gebräuchlich war z.B. "Personalleiter" (wobei es stark regionale und geschichtliche Unterschiede gab) und das heutzutage wahrscheinlich durch die amerikanisierte BWL mit englischen Wörtern verdrängt wurde. Du kannst aber auch sagen "einstellende Führungskraft", oder moderner: "Einstellungsmanager" oder "einstellender Manager" bzw. "Personalmanager" oder weitere Variationen davon.

Comment: "Einstellungsleiter" habe ich noch nie gehört, das kann also schwerlich traditionell gebräuchlich sein. Ich würde eher sowas wie "Ihre zukünftige Führungskraft" in einer Stellenanzeige finden.

Comment: @tofro: Im Osten schon

Comment: Personalleiter trifft das ganze nicht: "ist hauptberuflich für Personalfragen verantwortlicher Abteilungs- oder Hauptabteilungsleiter von Unternehmen, in denen planmäßige Personalarbeit betrieben wird." (Gabler Wirtschaftslexikon). "Einstellende Führungskraft" dann schon eher.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried different combinations of the suggestions and to my surprise the most Google Hits I got for
"Führungskraft mit Personalverantwortung".

So if you are looking for a job as a hiring manager that's probably what you are looking for. (Führungskraft can be replaced by Manager and different compounds with -leiter).

If you are refering to the hiring manager in an application process another option is "Personalentscheidungsträger".

Comment: Sorry, but this answer is "suboptimal". The question is about the "hiring manager", i.e., the one who is responsible for hiring somebody and then be their manager. None of your suggestions capture this meaning. Furthermore, Führungskraft mit Personalverantwortung is a weird tautology, because by definition, a FK is one that has PV. Personalentscheidungsträger is a very specific term typically related to personnel service providers.

Comment: Often "führen" is a translation from the english "to lead". A "team lead" would lead their team through the work day, but doesn't have the authority to hire and fire. See for example this newspaper article: https://www.zeit.de/karriere/beruf/2015-09/fuerungskraft-personalverantwortung-durchsetzungsvermoegen-befoerderung

Comment: "Führungskraft ohne Vorgesetztenfunktion" results in less than 700 google entries. I don't think we should use this article for reference. Anyways, no matter how you understand the term Führungskraft, "hiring manager" refers to a "manager" that is "hiring". Call it "hiring manager without any managing functions", then  we are still not looking for the "Führungskraft ohne jegliche wirkliche Führungsgewalt mit Personalverantwortung", but for the "einstellende Führungskraft ohne jegliche wirkliche Führungsgewalt.

Comment: For a definition of Führungskraft see https://wirtschaftslexikon.gabler.de/definition/fuehrungskraefte-34088 or look up Instanz (https://wirtschaftslexikon.gabler.de/definition/instanz-41792) and Weisungsbefugnis (https://wirtschaftslexikon.gabler.de/definition/weisungsbefugnis-49189)